# Access field within json reponse

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am trying to extract a particular field from an API request, and I will later used that for another task. Basically need to automate this request so I can keep up with timestamp of remote machine.

I can get the json list with this script I created:

```
from datetime import datetime
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://$hostname/api/profiler/1.13/reporting/timestamps.json", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("$username", "$password"))

time = response.json()

print(json.dumps(time, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This is the response :

```
[
    {
        "data_resolution": "min",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "day",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591743600,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "15mins",
        "datasource": "SERVICE",
        "end_time": 1591793100,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "flow",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "5mins",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793400,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "6hours",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591786800,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "hour",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591790400,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "15mins",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793100,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "min",
        "datasource": "FDS_TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 1587220140
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "5mins",
        "datasource": "FDS_TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793400,
        "start_time": 1587219900
    },
    {
        "data_resolution": "hour",
        "datasource": "FDS_TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591790400,
        "start_time": 1587218400
    }
]
```

I need  to extract this exact field (particularly the **end time** field):

```
{
        "data_resolution": "flow",
        "datasource": "TRAFFIC",
        "end_time": 1591793520,
        "start_time": 0
    },
```

I can't seem to extract that field.

Comment: What research have you done into `json` to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: the json you get is a list so all the logic of python list applies. Thus, first entry is `time[0]`, last is `time[-1]`. You can iterate over all values by using `for t in time:`.

Comment: for `end_time` of first entry you have `time[0]['end_time']`. you can iterate over all entries

Comment: quick noob question, will that give me the value too ?

Comment: use @ symbol with user name like @AlexandreAmaralBednell to send the user a message. Also, I did not understand your question. Explain.

Comment: @Doc thanks man, i managed to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to iterate over the json response: `list`;

After: `time = response.json()`

```
for entry in time:
    if entry.get('data_resolution') == 'flow':
        end_time = entry['end_time']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
[i['end_time'] for i in time if i['data_resolution']=='flow' and i['datasource']=='TRAFFIC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, this is how i did it. thanks @Doc

```
from datetime import datetime
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://10.65.170.112/api/profiler/1.13/reporting/timestamps.json", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))

time = response.json()


**for t in time:
    end_time = (time[3]["end_time"])**


print(end_time)
```